# For loop and Popup with liquid and jekyll

Tags: html, for-loop, popup, jekyll, liquid

I want to create a list of modal popups with a for-loop, each of them displaying different text.
The site is created with Jekyll with the Liquid templating engine.

In particular, I want to create the list of my scientific publications, for each of them with 2 icons: one for the bibtex entry and one for the abstract. This information is stored in a yaml file.

I m following this [simple tutorial for modal popups](https://youtu.be/MBaw_6cPmAw).

The popups work, but the text is the same for all the entries. How is possible to generate independent modal popups?

This is the html

```html
{% for papers in papers %}
  {% for content in paper.papers %}
    <a title="{{content.name}}"><i class='{{content.icon}}' data-modal-target="#modal"></i></a>
    <div class="modal" id="modal">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="title">{{content.name}}</div>
        <button data-close-button class="close-button">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- text to display -->
      <div class="modal-body">{{content.text}}</div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

and this is the Javascript code:

```js
const openModalIcons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]')
const closeModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]')
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay')

openModalIcons.forEach(icon => {
    icon.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const modal = document.querySelector(icon.dataset.modalTarget)
        openModal(modal)
    })
})

function openModal(modal) {
    if (modal == null) return
    modal.classList.add('active')
    overlay.classList.add('active')
}

closeModalButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const modal = button.closest('.modal')
        closeModal(modal)
    })
})

function closeModal(modal) {
    if (modal == null) return
    modal.classList.remove('active')
    overlay.classList.remove('active')
}

overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal.active')
    modals.forEach(modal => {
        closeModal(modal)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all your modals have `id="modal"`, so the selector `#modal` is probably always selecting the first one. The `id` attribute should be unique in the entire document.

Something like this should work:

```
{% for papers in papers %}
  {% for content in paper.papers %}
    <a title="{{content.name}}"><i class='{{content.icon}}' data-modal-target="#paperModal{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}_{{forloop.counter}}"></i></a>
    <div class="modal" id="paperModal{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}_{{forloop.counter}}">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="title">{{content.name}}</div>
        <button data-close-button class="close-button">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- text to display -->
      <div class="modal-body">{{content.text}}</div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Instead of the for loop counter, you could also use the paper name as the ID (as long as it's unique), e.g. `id="paperModal_{{content.name | slugify}}"`.

Edit: Edited the snippet to use `forloop.counter` and account for the nested for loop.

Comment: ```forloop.counter``` was not working, but I added an ID for everypaper (actualy the bibtex code) and ```paperModal_{{content.id | slugify}}_{{content.name}}``` is working perfectly